# jQuery - Load div from other domain and replace elements inside it

Tags: jquery, html

I have the current situation: I need to `.load` a `div` from another domain, and replace multiple elements inside it (URLs), some of them with the same classes. Here's an example:

```
<img class="InfoBarSmallElement" src="http://example.com/img.png" />
<img class="InfoBarSmallElement" src="http://example.com/img2.png" />
```

Into:

```
<img class="InfoBarSmallElement" src="mysite.com/img.png" />
<img class="InfoBarSmallElement" src="mysite.com/img2.png" />
```

Here's the script i'm using to load the div:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var contentURI = 'http://www.example.com/ .Div';
        $('.Result').load('../system/getp.php?url=' + contentURI);
    });
</script>
```

getp.php

```
<?php echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']); ?>
```

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can be done in php: 
file getp.php:

```
   echo str_replace(array('http://example.com'),array('mysite.com'), file_get_contents($_GET['url']) );
```

it is possible using JavaScript(JQuery):

```
$(function(){
    var contentURI = 'http://www.example.com/ .Div';
    $('.Result').load('../system/getp.php?url=' + contentURI, function() {
         $('.Result').html(($('.Result').html()).replace(new RegExp('http://example.com','g'), 'mysite.com');
    });
});
```

test replace all for jquery:

```js
var test_html=$('.Result').html();
console.log('orig=>'+test_html);
test_html=test_html.replace(new RegExp('http://example.com','g'), 'mysite.com');
$('.Result').html(test_html);
console.log('correct=>'+test_html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="Result"><a href="http://example.com/test.html">http://example.com/test.html</a><br><a href="http://example.com/test2.html">http://example.com/test2.html</a></div>
```

Comment: the jquery script only replaces the first element, but the php works like a charm, thank you bro!